# How not to get first names (neither full nor abbreviations) in in-text citations?

Tags: biblatex, citing, author

I need to conform my citations with the format my lecturer wants. I was told to never have the first names in an in-text citation. In case there are several authors with the same last name, they should be distinguished by a letter behind the year. The citation style is author year; I'm using biblatex like this atm:
 \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true
  ]{biblatex}

Answer (score 0):

I found out that uniquename=false removes the first names of the authors. However, I am not sure whether the citations are unique in any case. I guess it's all fine as long as authors with the same name didn't publish in the same year.

Comment: page 304 of the biblatex` documentation might be interesting.